# Database Saying Undefined Bindings When Compiling First Query

Tags: postgresql, express, heroku, sqlite, knex.js

I was developing a backend with a SQLite3 and I deployed to heroku with postgresQL, the databse worked fine when it was in development, everything worked as expected and now I'm getting an error stating

```
2019-02-22T11:51:48.768183+00:00 app[web.1]: error Error: Undefined 
binding(s) detected when compiling FIRST query: select * from "users" 
where "id" = ? limit ?
2019-02-22T11:51:48.768200+00:00 app[web.1]: at QueryCompiler_PG.toSQL 
(/app/node_modules/knex/lib/query/compiler.js:85:13)
```

However, there are no undefined bindings

My schema looks like

```
exports.up = function (knex, Promise) {
return knex.schema.createTable('users', users => {
users.increments('id')
users.string('name').notNullable();
users.string('email').notNullable();
users.string('username').notNullable();
users.string('password').notNullable();
users.string('role').notNullable();
})
```

};

The Query looks like

```
router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
const user = req.body;
const hashedPass = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, 12)
user.password = hashedPass;
var username = user.username
db.insertUser(user)
.then(ids => {
  const id = ids[0];
  db.findByID(id)
    .then(user => {
      const token = (newToken(user));
      res.status(200).json({ id: user.id, 
username:username,token:token});
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("error", err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Something went wrong' })
    })
})
.catch(err => {
  res.status(500).send(err);
});
});
```

Lastly, the helper function is...

```
findByID: (id) => {
return db('users').where('id', id).first();
}
```

Do you know what would be causing such an error, I have tried to search for it on here, and Google and can't find it. Thank you much in advance!

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to develop using one database technology and deploy using another. I strongly recommend that you use Postgres in development. But that's not the cause of your error. Have you run your migrations on Heroku? Are you sure the `users` table exists?

Comment: yes, I have ran migrations with Heroku.

Comment: Inspect your `db.insertUser(user)` return result. I'm almost sure you've got something else rather than an array you are expecting to get.